# Browser incompatibility when serving a PDF using PHP fopen or readfile

Tags: php, internet-explorer, header, fopen, readfile

I've been going around in circles trying to serve a PDF securely using variations of fopen() and readfile(). Most methods work fine in Firefox and Chrome whether I'm on Windows/OSX/iOS but **no** method will work with Internet Explorer or Safari. I've tried all sorts of header variations based on what others have suggested but no luck.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['user_is_logged_in'] === true || $_SESSION['admin_user_is_logged_in'] === true) {

    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $path = "www.mypath.com/$name";
    $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');

    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
    //Experimented with this but all it does is force a download instead of opening in browser. 
    //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name);

    readfile($path);

    //alternately tried
    //passthru($fp);
}
else {
    echo "You do not have permission to view this file. Please <a href='../../index.php'>log in</a>.";
}

exit;
?>
```

If I use Content-Disposition in the header the result is any PDF downloaded in Safari or IE is 0KB and not readable. Without content-disposition IE and Safari just hang on a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

These are some advices I would like to share:

Try to use localpaths ie. windows (c:\folder\resource.pdf) or linux (/var/www/project/resouce.pdf).

Print your $path and check that is a file generated correctly.

Then try this piece of code, that is which I use:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$this->filename}.pdf");

readfile($path);
unlink($path);
```